# How to configure the lotus notes java API in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am under the need to configure my **spring MVC** project with **lotus notes Java API**. We need to extract the emails which are present in lotus notes with the help of **.NSF** file. I searched online but I didn't get any clarified answer. Please answer, if any one know how to configure the spring MVC project with lotus notes. If any existing links are there, please attach that too with your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like any other Java project that integrates with Notes and Domino.

I.e., you can either install a licensed copy of Lotus Notes (only if you are running in a 32 bit JVM) or Lotus Domino (32 or 64 bit JVM) and add the notes.jar file that comes with it to your project, or you can get the NCSO.jar from a Lotus Domino installation and add it to your project. Note that the latter option will only work if the Domino server that you re connecting to is confugured to support IIOP.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and you really cleared my main doubt.Now i installed the **licensed domino lotus notes** and i had taken the notes.jar from server and add with my project then i try to hit my lotus server with username and password it throws error message { Notes Exception: Could not get IOR from Domino Server: http://ipaddress/diiop_ior.txt }.I think solution for this error is present in above answer but i **don't know how to configure the IIOP in server** .please send the steps that i should take to configure the IIOP in sever.once again thanks for your support @Richard Schwartz

Comment: It's not a straightforward single path. There are multiple steps and there are a couple of different ways your Domino server could be configured that affect where you go to do parts of the configuration. A good starting point can be found here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/DIIOP_Usage_and_Troubleshooting_Guide.  That should give you the basic vocabulary, and searching in the Domino Admin client's help will get you the rest.